# IE8 :after content delay appearance using jQuery UI Dialog

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

I am using `:after` to add asterisks to labels that are required:

```
.field-name
{
    color: #444;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 0.85em;
    line-height: 2em;
}

.field-name.required:after
{
  content: '*';
  color: #ff0000;  
}
```

This works great when the content is not inside of a jQuery dialog. However, when using a jQuery dialog, the asterisks are only shown when the dialog is hovered-over. See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QkXLR/7/) for an an example in IE8. Click the button and then move the mouse over the actual dialog window. In all other modern browsers, this works as expected. Is this a known bug?

Comment: You do know that you shouldn't use CSS to modify your content right? I did try your jsFiddle using IE9, but in IE8 browser mode, works fine for me. Not sure if I have to set the iFrame browser mode too though

Comment: @jValdron - Why are you saying "you shouldn't use CSS to modify your content"? Using `:after` and `:content` is a very common method for styling things like breadcrumbs.

Comment: CSS is meant for adding presentation to the page, and not content. For breadcrumbs, I usually use a background and a padding -left on a + selector. But yeah, there should be a reason they added :content and :after :)

Comment: @jValdron - Did you just quote [QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/content.html)? Seriously though, `:content` has its valid use cases. I think this is a perfect example of where it makes sense. Also, when you're printing a page (e.g. wikipedia), a great use is to use `content: "(" attr(href) ")"` to actually display the href when printing.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use CSS to add the star.  Use javascript's method to add text to the end of a Dom element.  CSS is not content, it's meant for styling the content.

Comment: Why would I use jQuery for something that is so simple using CSS. Additionally, adding the asterisk *is styling* the label. What do you mean by "jQuery is getting confused"? This is a standard way of doing this. Additionally, it works in every other modern browser (IE9 included).

Comment: I updated my question.  IE (in the past) has had a lot of problems, bugs and presentation bugs so IE 8 (even though it's more mature) still has presentation problems.

Comment: Dean Edwards has a script, (google his name) that can fix various presentation problems with IE browsers.  It might be able to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

These asterisks won't be read by screen readers when added through the CSS property `content` (except VoiceOver, maybe), even though it's an important information that is being conveyed.

You should add them server-side: everybody will see them, with or without running scripts. You should also add at the beginning of your form a sentence like 'Fields marked with a * are required', because not everybody knows what these stars mean.

Answer (score 0):

We know IE8 has [issues rendering generated content](http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-typography-experiment/demo/bugs.html). The z-index isn't being set properly. I suggest setting a higher z-index on the parent element as mentioned [here](http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/). It's possible the jQuery UI dialog's changing the positioning attribute when you hover over it. Unfortunately, I can't really test this as I'm not running IE8 here but I hope this helps.

Comment: I'll keep looking in case I run across something.